# How to use globally installed nodejs in scripted pipeline on jenkins?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, continuous-integration, devops, cicd

This is my jenkinsfile (I don't need freestyle job solution):

```
node('k8s-jenkins-agent') {
    env.COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'hostname').trim()
    env.GRADLE_USER_HOME = "${env.WORKSPACE}/.gradle"
    env.JAVA_HOME="${tool 'jdk-1.8.0_321'}"
    env.PATH="${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
    def branches = ["master"]
    try {
        stage 'Build'
          checkout scm
          sh 'gradle -version'
          sh 'node --version'
    } catch (e) {
      throw e
    }
}
```

This gives me `script.sh: line 1: node: command not found` error.
I have tried asking chatGPT an tried all suggestions but none worked.

Comment: If you run `sh '/usr/local/bin/node--version'`, does it work?

Comment: @M B No, got error:  `script.sh: line 1: /usr/local/bin/node--version: No such file or directory`

Comment: There should be a whitespace btw I wrote it wrong: `node --version`. However, if this doesn't work, it means that node isn't installed since that is where the executable should be.

Comment: for jenkins,  I think this path is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Adding nodejs tool and modifying path as below solved the issue.

```
env.NODEJS_HOME = "${tool '[name_of_installed_nodejs]'}"
env.PATH="${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}:${env.NODEJS_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
```

This syntax is surprisingly not available anywhere.

resulting jenkinsfile looks like:

```
#!groovy
node('k8s-jenkins-agent') {
    env.COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'hostname').trim()
    env.GRADLE_USER_HOME = "${env.WORKSPACE}/.gradle"
    env.JAVA_HOME="${tool 'jdk-1.8.0_321'}"
    env.NODEJS_HOME = "${tool 'NodeJS-14.20.0'}"
    env.PATH="${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}:${env.NODEJS_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
    def branches = ["master"]
    try {
        stage 'Build'
          checkout scm
          sh 'gradle -version'
          sh 'node --version'

    } catch (e) {
      throw e
    }
}
```